# Pointer and structures cause Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I've been working in a ColorSegmentationAlgorithm with openCV. I finished the segmentation, but now I'm collecting the object on the picture by color. In order to do that I've got the "rows" of the image compressed in RLE and they are refered each other with pointers.

At this point (I think) that everything is all right because I printed on the console the results of "clusters" compressed in RLE and everything seems to be ok. Then I look over the list of structures to create a new variable that will represent the object (With bouncin box, centroid, etc.). But, here's the trouble, I don't now exactly why when call the content of the pointer in a "random case" it's bad loaded (It's like variables were shifted): for example if the structure has this content:

(int i, int je, int js, "pointer" *child) --> {1, 1 , 1, 0x0AB0231A}

its loaded --> {1, 0x0AB0231A, 1, 1}

And If the next "child" is called then it provoke a **segmentation fault (Core dumped) error**

So... Here is a part of the code:

```
struct LineObjRLE {
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int js;
    unsigned int je;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int color;
    struct LineObjRLE *parent;
    struct LineObjRLE *child;
};
```

---

```
struct LineObjRLE auxRLE = aRLE[i][j];
vector<struct LineObjRLE> obj;
while (1) {
    obj.push_back(auxRLE);
    printf("auxRLE: parent: %d  --  child: %d\n",
            auxRLE.parent, auxRLE.child);
    if (auxRLE.child == NULL)
        break;
    auxRLE = *auxRLE.child;
}
```

- aRLE (array of RLE) is a vector variable that is created while segmentation.

Here I've got some results: (The pointers are displayed as **int**, but they are right)

```
---------------------------------
k: 1 
auxRLE: parent: 0  --  child: 55035088
auxRLE: parent: 55036080  --  child: 55505600
auxRLE: parent: 55035088  --  child: 0
---------------------------------
k: 2 
auxRLE: parent: 0  --  child: 55035248
auxRLE: parent: 0  --  child: 0
---------------------------------
k: 3 
auxRLE: parent: 0  --  child: 55035288
auxRLE: parent: 55036200  --  child: 55505720
auxRLE: parent: 55035288  --  child: 0
---------------------------------
k: 4 
auxRLE: parent: 0  --  child: 55035528
auxRLE: parent: 0  --  child: 55505840
auxRLE: parent: 55035528  --  child: 0
---------------------------------
k: 5 
auxRLE: parent: 0  --  child: 55035688
auxRLE: parent: 0  --  child: 0
---------------------------------
k: 6 
auxRLE: parent: 0  --  child: 55035808
auxRLE: parent: 18  --  child: 6
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The segmentation occurs when "the shift" that I described before happens. When I examined all the content of the structure I saw that the pointers where in other variables of the structure and the pointer has other values (so point to 6 or 18 generate the error).

PD: Instead of saving also "parents" pointer, I only use the "child" direction for look over the structures.

I hope I explained my self, and someone could help me.
Thanks in advance!

CODE:

```
    while (waitKey(1)) {

        t1 = clock(); // Time counter1
        device >> frame; // Get the frame from the camera
        imshow("Ori", frame); // Show the original frame
        //medianBlur(frame, frame, 5);
        imageBGR2HSV(&frame); // Transform image from BGR to HSV

        int n = frame.channels(); // Count the number of image's channels to use the pointer

        int color;
        short int js, colorRLE = -1, jRLE = -1; // Variables for RLE encode
        for (int i = 0; i < frame.rows; i++) {
            uchar* ptr = frame.ptr<uchar>(i); // Pointer to i row
            vector<struct LineObjRLE> temp;
            for (int j = 0; j < frame.cols; j++) {
                // Proximate the color to a cluster
                color = CS.whichColorHSV(
                        (color3cInt ) { ptr[n * j], ptr[n * j + 1], ptr[n
                                        * j + 2] });
                // RLE encoding
                if (!j) {
                    colorRLE = color;
                    jRLE = 1;
                    js = 0;
                } else {
                    if (j == frame.cols - 1) {
                        temp.push_back((LineObjRLE ) { i, js, j, j - js, color,
                                NULL, NULL });
                    } else if (color == colorRLE) {
                        jRLE = jRLE + 1;
                    } else if (color != colorRLE) {
                        temp.push_back((LineObjRLE ) { i, js, j, j - js, color,
                                NULL, NULL });
                        colorRLE = color;
                        jRLE = 1;
                        js = j;
                    }
                }
                // Change the color (Improve assigning directly the BGR color, save from using imageHSV2BGR)
                if (color != -1) {
                    ptr[n * j] = CS.ColorCluster[color].a;
                    ptr[n * j + 1] = CS.ColorCluster[color].b;
                    ptr[n * j + 2] = CS.ColorCluster[color].c;
                } else {
                    ptr[n * j] = CS.ColorCluster[0].a;
                    ptr[n * j + 1] = CS.ColorCluster[0].b;
                    ptr[n * j + 2] = CS.ColorCluster[0].c;
                }
            }
            aRLE.push_back(temp);
            if (i) { // Except the first line that can't be child of any object (only parent) start joining objects grouped in LineObjRLE variables
                unsigned int j = 0, jp = 0; // Pointer to current and previous LineObjRLE
                unsigned int pp = aRLE[i - 1][jp].size, pc = aRLE[i][j].size; // Pointer to previous and current col
                bool end = false; // Flag to manage the loop
                while (!end) {
                    if ((aRLE[i - 1][jp].je > aRLE[i][j].js
                            && aRLE[i - 1][jp].js < aRLE[i][j].je)
                            && aRLE[i - 1][jp].color == aRLE[i][j].color) {
                        aRLE[i][j].parent = &(aRLE[i - 1][jp]);
                        aRLE[i - 1][jp].child = &(aRLE[i][j]);
                        //printf("Parent is %d and says that child is: %d\n", &aRLE[i - 1][jp], aRLE[i - 1][jp].child);
                        //printf("Child is %d and says that parent is: %d\n", &aRLE[i][j], aRLE[i][j].parent);
                    }
                    if (j == aRLE[i].size() - 1 || jp == aRLE[i - 1].size() - 1)
                        end = true;
                    if (pp > pc) {
                        pc += aRLE[i][j].size;
                        j++;
                    } else {
                        pp += aRLE[i - 1][jp].size;
                        jp++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Run vertically to identifies the parents of the objects

        int k = 0; //Index for final object
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < aRLE.size(); i++) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < aRLE.at(i).size(); j++) {
                if (aRLE[i][j].parent == NULL && aRLE[i][j].child != NULL) {
                    printf("---------------------------------\n");
                    printf("k: %d \n", k);
                    printf("aRLE: parent: %d  --  child: %d\n",
                            aRLE[i][j].parent, aRLE[i][j].child);
                    // Grow from the seed
                    struct LineObjRLE auxRLE = aRLE[i][j];
                    vector<struct LineObjRLE> obj;
                    while (1) {
                        obj.push_back(auxRLE);
                        printf("auxRLE: parent: %d  --  child: %d\n",
                                auxRLE.parent, auxRLE.child);
                        if (auxRLE.child == NULL)
                            break;
                        auxRLE = *auxRLE.child;
                    }
                    k = k + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        // Calculate increment of time
        t2 = clock();
        float dif = (((float) t2 - (float) t1) / 1000000.0F) * 1000;
        printf("FINISHED IN %f \n", dif);

        imageHSV2BGR(&frame);

        imshow("Viewer", frame); // Show the image segmented
        aRLE.clear();
        objs.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code looks all right at first glance. The problem is probably in the code you haven't shown us. If you post a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org), I'm sure someone will spot the bug.

Comment: Okay, I thought that the trouble was in that part of the code, because It's where it "crash". I'm going to add it at the end of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, it seems you are storing pointers to objects inside the `std::vector<RLE>`. For example, I spotted:

```
aRLE[i][j].parent = &(aRLE[i - 1][jp]);
```

At the same time I don't see any call to `aRLE.reserve()` which would ensure that the objects don't get relocated upon adding new objects. I suspect, that the vector needs to reallocate memory, releasing already pointed to memory, and you get a bunch of stale pointers.

The easiest ways to test the theory if you create stale pointers are those:

- If you know the final size of the data structure ahead of time, you can use `std::vector<T>::reserve(size_type n)` to tell the data structure to allocate sufficient space to hold up to `n` elements.
- If you don't know the size but you only need something which looks like an array and you only append at the end or the beginning, you can replace `std::vector<RLE>` by `std::deque<RLE>`: Although adding objects at either end may change iterators, it won't change the location of objects.

Comment: Initially I don't know the size of the object, but If I reserved the memory, the code don't crash, so the trouble is there as you say. Thanks for the answer